# Creating an html formatted file to be opened by Excel

Tags: html, excel, file-extension

I am trying to export a spreadsheet file from a website. The data is a bit too complex for a simple csv, so I figured the best way to do it was to format it into a file containing nothing but an HTML table. If I give it a .xls extension, it will open, but only after throwing an error and asking for confirmation. Is there a way to set up the file so that Excel knows that it is supposed to have HTML code in it, and so that the OS knows that Excel is supposed to open it?

This is going to be used by people who aren't going think to open Excel and drag the file in or open it from inside Excel. They're going to be double-clicking on the file.

Comment: Instead of using HTML, what about formatting it using XML that excel can understand? You can use this reference for the tags to create: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx

Comment: That's a much better idea. Thanks.

Comment: I found a tool, EPPlus, that did exactly what I needed.